# Would the alchemy gate of people be empty while god was inside Father?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist

If someone tried human transmutation and went in front of their gate, while God was inside Father, would they see emptiness inside their gate?

Comment: I think the answer is probably "nobody knows," but maybe someone with better knowledge of the manga can comment?